# Reset display property with @mediaquery after change it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a button (**.sidebar-button**), which hides/displays the sidebar. @mediaqueries hide the sidebar when the screen size is < 800px, and automatically show the sidebar when the screen size is > 800px , so everything is right.

the problem is when I go to perform a click on the button (**.sidebar-button**).

the logic of the button is correct, but when I make a click on the button, and then increase the size of the screen one of the main div (.sidebar/.event) remains invisible even though I have entered this @mediaquery

```
@media (min-width: 800px)  {
    .sidebar{
        display: block;
    }
    .event{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

### javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var flagEvent = false;

  $(".sidebar-button").bind('touchstart click', function() {
    if (!flagEvent) {
      flagEvent = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        flagEvent = false;
      }, 100);

      if ($(".sidebar").css("display") == "none") {
        $(".sidebar").css("display", "block");
        $(".event").css("display", "none");
      } else {
        $(".sidebar").css("display", "none");
        $(".event").css("display", "block");
      }

    }
    return false
  });
});

$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", listenResizeEvent));

function listenResizeEvent() {
  /*if($(window).width() >= 800){
      $(".sidebar").css("display" , "block");
      $(".event").css("display" , "block");
  }*/
}
```

### css

```
html {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #004050;
  background: #004050;
  margin: 0;
}
::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}
.forboth {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.logo {
  background-image: url(../img/logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 271px;
  height: 111px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  margin: 10px;
}
.cat-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
.cat-menu > div {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  float: left;
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.cat-menu > div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #2c86ee;
  background: #2c86ee;
}
.cat-menu > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #6cb71e;
  background: #6cb71e;
}
.cat-menu > div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #d44a27;
  background: #d44a27;
}
.cat-menu > div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #af1a3f;
  background: #af1a3f;
}
.cat-menu > div:nth-child(5) {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.container-data {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 27%;
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
}
.sidebar .sidebar-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.event {
  width: 73%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
.search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #ff9201;
  background: #ff9201;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.sidebar-button {
  float: left;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  /* FIX FOR JSFIDDLE*/
  height: 40px;
  /* FIX FOR JSFIDDLE*/
  background: red;
  /* FIX FOR JSFIDDLE*/
}
/*.sidebar-button > span::before{
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
}*/

.search-textfield {
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.textfield {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.search-button {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.search-button > span::before {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
}
.sidebar-user {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff7801;
  background: #ff7801;
}
.sidebar-user-div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-user-div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-user-div11 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.sidebar-user-div12 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-user-div12 > span::before {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .cat-menu > div {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .cat-menu > div {
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .header .logo {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .cat-menu > div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .cat-menu > div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .cat-menu > div:nth-child(3) {
    /*float: none;*/
    width: 50%;
  }
  .cat-menu > div:nth-child(4) {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

### html

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat-menu">
    <div>TEST1</div>
    <div>TEST2</div>
    <div>TEST3</div>
    <div>TEST4</div>
    <div class="forboth"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-data">

    <div class="search">
      <div class="sidebar-button">
        <span class="flaticon-menu55"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="search-button">
        <span class="flaticon-search9"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="search-textfield">
        <input placeholder="cerca.." class="textfield" />
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-content">

        <div class="sidebar-user">
          <div class="sidebar-user-div1">
            <div class="sidebar-user-div11">
              User name
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-user-div12">
              <span class="flaticon-user62"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="forboth"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar-user-div2">
            Non sei tu? LOGOUT
          </div>
        </div>


        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="forboth"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolomonili/df2f8qm7/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in your click handler you're setting the css on the element to `display:none`, which gets added to the elements inline style. i.e `<div class="sidebar" style="display: none;">`. Then when the screen size changes to above 800, the media css rule changes the style on the element but the inline style element overrides the css rule so element stays hidden. Instead of setting the css of the element directly, add/remove a class to it to hide/show it so the media css rule can override it.

```
if($(".sidebar").hasClass("show")){
    $(".sidebar").addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
    $(".event").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
}else{
    $(".sidebar").addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
    $(".event").addClass("hide").removeClass("show");
}
```

Update:

See http://jsfiddle.net/df2f8qm7/2/

I added .show and .hide rules inside media:

```
@media (max-width: 800px)  {
.sidebar{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.event{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-content{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.sidebar-button{
    display: block;
}
.show
{
    display:block;
}
.hide
{
    display:none;
}
}

@media (min-width: 800px)  {
.sidebar{
    display: block;
}
.event{
    display: block;
}
.show
{
    display:block;
}

.hide
{
    display:block;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I created two classes .show { display: block; } .hide { display: none; }, but does not work , when I press the button the div is not hidden

Comment: the class is successfully added, but looking at the console of GoogleChrome I noticed that the property display: none/block is not accepted